# XAML control layout with overlay other controls on view

Tags: forms, xamarin, layout, autocomplete, custom-controls

I want to create custom entry control with suggestions. In my app i want to use [XF.Material library](https://github.com/contrix09/XF-Material-Library) - my app need to be in Material Design for iOS and Android. Now I want to implement autocomplete entry with Material Entry from Library, so i' trying to modify [Xamarin Custom Controls Autocomplete](https://github.com/DottorPagliaccius/Xamarin-Custom-Controls/blob/master/src/Xamarin.CustomControls.AutoCompleteView/AutoCompleteView.xaml)

It's working, but i want to display Frame in front of other controls. Currently Frame with items is not z-indexed and moves other controls down. Is there any way to achieve hiding other controls behind the frame?

1. Entry without list

[image]

2. Entry with list:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
             xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:XF.Material.Forms.UI;assembly=XF.Material.Forms"
             x:Class="MyApp.Controls.MaterialAutocomplete">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="0">
            <ui:MaterialTextField x:Name="MainEntry" TextChanged="SearchText_TextChanged" Focused="SearchText_Focused" Unfocused="SearchText_Unfocused" />
            <StackLayout x:Name="SuggestedItemsContainerBottom" IsVisible="false" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="10,-17,10,0">
                <Frame x:Name="SuggestedItemsOuterContainer" BackgroundColor="White" HasShadow="false" OutlineColor="Silver" Padding="0">
                    <controls:RepeaterView x:Name="SuggestedItemsRepeaterView" ShowSeparator="true" SeparatorColor="Silver" SeparatorHeight="1" />
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

My View with control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:XF.Material.Forms.UI;assembly=XF.Material.Forms"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.AddAddressPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <controls:MaterialAutocomplete 
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    AlwaysShowUnderline="True"
                    OpenOnFocus="true"
                    SearchMember="Value" 
                    SuggestionBorderColor="Silver" 
                    ShowSeparator="true" MaxResults="5" EmptyText="No element found"
                    SuggestionBackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" 
                    Placeholder="Miasto" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" SelectedItemCommand="{Binding CitySelectedCommand}">
                    <controls:MaterialAutocomplete.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="3">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Value}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:MaterialAutocomplete.ItemTemplate>
                </controls:MaterialAutocomplete>
                <Label Text=" tesst"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Not sure I understood correctly your prob. You want the "tesst" label to stay at its position ? Where is this label in your UI hierarchy ?

Comment: Yes, i want label to stay on initial position. I've updated post. Added view xaml with my custom control and label.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to switch the `StackLayout` to a `Grid` and put everything in it, then you'll have overlay (that's what I like with `Grid`). You can play with `VerticalOptions` of `MaterialAutoComplete` and `Label` and adjust everything with `Margin` property of each if `VerticalOptions` property does not fit exactly how you would like it to be displayed.

I did test this and its working (in one of our project), maybe you can change the `Margin` values on the `Label` for example, or add some on the `MaterialAutoComplete`, or try to do something with `Padding` property of the grid too.

**Be careful on the order**, you have to put the `Label` first in the `Grid` if you want it to be "under" your `MaterialAutoComplete` control.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:XF.Material.Forms.UI;assembly=XF.Material.Forms"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.AddAddressPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <Grid>
                <Label VerticalOptions = "Center" Margin="0,0,0,100" Text=" tesst"/>
                <controls:MaterialAutocomplete 
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    AlwaysShowUnderline="True"
                    OpenOnFocus="true"
                    SearchMember="Value" 
                    VerticalOptions = "StartAndExpand"
                    SuggestionBorderColor="Silver" 
                    ShowSeparator="true" MaxResults="5" EmptyText="No element found"
                    SuggestionBackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" 
                    Placeholder="Miasto" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" SelectedItemCommand="{Binding CitySelectedCommand}">
                    <controls:MaterialAutocomplete.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="3">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Value}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:MaterialAutocomplete.ItemTemplate>
                </controls:MaterialAutocomplete>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Your's tip is good, and controls shows properly, but when i have second entry in next row, and when I tap on autocomplete proposals, the entry below list will be focused, and my selection is unsuccessful. I still need something like "z-index" for control

Comment: Then maybe you can set `IsEnabled` property to `false` or `InputTransparent` to `true` for the entry when you tap in autocomplete or when it is open.

Comment: Nothing changed, still when I tap on list with suggestions 'xaml" think's that I clicked on inputTransparent/Disabled entry. When I change to "StackLayout" my suggestions works fine when I select one, but I lost "overlap" effect, and my other controls are moving down.

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide bindings for margins and maybe width/height. I've done that already this way and this worked.
But autosuggestion is normally done with key and timer event. The last one is for a timeout between short repeadetly key events. There are some examples on codeproject.